# Mobile's virtual keyboard destroy design

Tags: keyboard, virtual-keyboard

First, sorry for my bad english. I'll try to explain the best i can.

So, i have problem with mobile's keyboards. When i try to search something on my search-bar, the virtual keyboard appears and destroy my design. Here you can see my problem :

**Normal**

[image]

**Bug**

[image]

On the first screen, you can see " Barre de recherche " means " SearchBar" and " Contenu du site " means " Website content "

On the second screen, as you can see, the content hide my searchbar, only when keyboard is open...

I don't really know how to solve this.

Comment: Please provide relevant code

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row bgBlanc clrNoir hidden-lg hidden-md search-container hidden-search-container">
        <div class="col-24 flex flexRow flexAlignCenter-sm flexJustifySpace-sm">
            <form class="row search-bar searchFormMob fullW" name="quickFind" action='advanced_search_result.php' method="get" autocomplete="off">
                <input class="tup col-offset-1 col-18 col-sm-20 keywords fs40" type="search" name="keywords" placeholder="<?php echo TEXT_SEARCH_PEF_KEYWORDS;  ?>" style="min-height:10rem; width:100%;border-style:none;opacity: 0.4;">
                <!-- <button class="submitBtn-search col-2 ffwi pt15 fs60" type="submit">&#xe602;</button>   -->
                <button class="submitBtn-search col-2 col-sm-2 ffwi pt15 fs60" type="submit">
                    <svg width="44px" height="44px" viewBox="0 0 22 22" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                        <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                            <g id="Icones-nav-2" transform="translate(-805.000000, -25.000000)" fill-rule="nonzero" fill="#000000">
                                <g id="ic_search_black_24px-copy" transform="translate(805.000000, 25.000000)">
                                    <path d="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" id="Shape"></path>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you should put the code _in your question_. Answers are only to be used for when your question is actually completely answered (which is actually why hardly anyone has looked at this... it looks like it is answered already).